# Where's the error in this piece of threaded code?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I created a class which is used as a cache provider. It uses a Map, timestamped map entries and it spawns a Thread which performs cleanup every so often. This class is used in a web application. This web application had a problem where POST would take 30 seconds. I traced the problem to this cache class, eliminating it resolves the problem.

I have tried my best to find the error in this class but I can't. Please help me out here.
Assume User class is some kind of POJO describing the user.

```
public class UserStore implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private static volatile UserStore instance;
private static Thread cleanUpThread;
private static Map<String, TimeStampedToken<User>> tokenMap = new HashMap<String, TimeStampedToken<User>>();
public static UserStore getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
         synchronized(UserStore.class) {
             if (instance == null) {
                 instance = new UserStore();
                 cleanUpThread = new Thread(new CleanUpWorker());
                 cleanUpThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(instance);
                 cleanUpThread.start();
             }
         }
    }
    return instance;
}
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable instanceof ThreadDeath) {
         cleanUpThread = new Thread(new CleanUpWorker());
         cleanUpThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
         cleanUpThread.start();
         throw (ThreadDeath)throwable;
    }

}
private static class CleanUpWorker implements Runnable {
    private static final long CLEANUP_CYCLE_MS = 300000;
    private static final long OBJECT_LIVE_TIME = 299900;
    public void run() {
        long sleepRemaining; 
        long sleepStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sleepRemaining = CLEANUP_CYCLE_MS; 
        while (true) {
            try {
                sleepStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Thread.sleep(sleepRemaining);
                cleanUp();
                sleepRemaining = CLEANUP_CYCLE_MS;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                sleepRemaining = System.currentTimeMillis() - sleepStart;
            }
        }
    }
    private void cleanUp() {
        Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        synchronized(tokenMap) {
            for (String user : tokenMap.keySet()) {
                TimeStampedToken<User> tok = tokenMap.get(user);
                if (tok.accessed + OBJECT_LIVE_TIME < currentTime) {
                    tokenMap.remove(user);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
public void addToken(User tok) {
    synchronized(tokenMap) {
        tokenMap.put(tok.getUserId(), new TimeStampedToken<User>(tok));
    }
}
public User getToken(String userId) {
    synchronized(tokenMap) {
        TimeStampedToken<User> user = tokenMap.get(userId);
        if (user != null) {
            user.accessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return user.payload;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
private static class TimeStampedToken<E> {
    public TimeStampedToken(E payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
    public long accessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public E payload; 
}
}
```

Comment: What *is* the problem exactly, with what your cache class does? It works incorrectly (functionally)? Or it works slower than you want (causing the POST to take too long)? If so, which method call is taking too much time?

Comment: Why are you restarting a Thread, only when it is specifically told to stop?

Comment: I looks like you are trying to implement a cache with an expiry date.  There are much simpler ways of implementing this, or you could use library which does this already.

Comment: Man, don't try to restart a thread. If you are having exceptions, let them propagate, log, and fix your code.

Comment: @MisterSmith You only get a ThreadDeath if the code has specifically called Thread.stop() which makes it a stranger choice for a restart. :P

Comment: 1st reply-It's not working slow - as in slow algorithmically, since there's no way that code should take 30 seconds on cache map with 10 elements, only 1 full element. There's seems to be some sort of thread lockup in combination with Thread.sleep going on. I have been unable to find where specifically the wait is produced.
2nd reply-I am not restarting, I am just starting a new thread when old one dies. Threads can die for variety of reasons and I didn't want to lose clean-up thread.
3rd reply-I figured out a better way since then, but I am still frustrated I don't know why this class failed

Comment: Consider using Guava's CacheBuilder (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html). It will result in a tested, more efficient cache, and it doesn't need any cleanup thread.

Comment: If there's a bottleneck, seems that it may be that `tokenMap`. But just use a profiler to be sure. An about the "restart", use try-catch instead of that ugly mechanism. You'll remove a lot of complexity with the change.

Comment: I was catching ThreadDeath specifically because I've read somewhere that threads can die for reasons other than Thread.stop and uncaught exceptions, that is, that the JVM doesn't guarantee that Thread will keep running perpetually in case of absence of Thread.stop and other thread commands, uncaught exceptions and JVM exit.

Comment: Yes, uncaught Errors. Other than these, I don't know any other. I'd like to read that article you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would approach it. With multi-threaded code, simplicity is often the best approach as its more likely to work.

(the third parameter `true`of the LinkedHashMap means that iterators over this Map follow the order of access rather than order of insertion)

```
public enum UserStore {
    ;

    interface User {
        String getUserId();
    }

    // a LRU cache with a timestamp.
    private static final Map<String, TimeStampedToken<User>> tokenMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, TimeStampedToken<User>>(16, 0.7f, true);
    private static final long OBJECT_LIVE_TIME = 299900;

    public static synchronized void addToken(User tok) {
        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // clean up as we go
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, TimeStampedToken<User>>> iter = tokenMap.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            final Map.Entry<String, TimeStampedToken<User>> next = iter.next();
            if (next.getValue().accessed + OBJECT_LIVE_TIME >= now)
                // the map is ordered by access time so there are no more to clean up.
                break;
            iter.remove();
        }
        // add a new entry
        tokenMap.put(tok.getUserId(), new TimeStampedToken<User>(tok, now));
    }

    public static synchronized User getToken(String userId) {
        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        TimeStampedToken<User> user = tokenMap.get(userId);
        if (user == null)
            return null;

        user.accessed = now;
        return user.payload;
    }

    static class TimeStampedToken<E> {
        long accessed;
        final E payload;

        TimeStampedToken(E payload, long now) {
            this.payload = payload;
            accessed = now;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks weird to me...

sleepRemaining = System.currentTimeMillis() - sleepStart;

...surely it should be...

sleepRemaining = CLEANUP_CYCLE_MS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - sleepStart);